# How to create project in SVN

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I have access to SVN server and I need to add new folder project1, which must contain such folders as trunk, branches, tags for this project. Could you guide me how to do that using tortoise SVN assuming that project is empty and I want to create just folders structure.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Right-click on any folder and choose *TortoiseSVN - Repo Brower...*. Enter the URL of your repository. Then right-click on the root node of the empty tree on the left, and choose *Create folder...*.

Comment: Do I have to create these folders manually? And where I have to commit?

Comment: If you create them in the repo browser, the commit will be automatic after each directory creation. You could also create the folder structure on your disk, and then use *TortoiseSVN - Import...* to import the structure into the repo. You could also discover all this by yourself by right-clicking and choosing *TortoiseSVN - Help*, and go to "Getting Started".

Comment: @JBNizet Your comment is more useful than your answer. :-)